# which version support PR2

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI:

can  you tell me    which   ros  version  support    deskop-full-PR2   ？
where  is   download    PR2  e-book    ？

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189502/which--version---support----pr2/) by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last version of ROS that had full support for the PR2 was Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on 2014-08-08**:
thanks  .are   you   research   human-robot ?